# Angular2 render multilevel Firebase Object

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm having trouble rendering the value of an object that is retrieved from firebase. The close I have to making this work it as follows:

Just for reference the data comes from here, it's doing fine:

the data is structures like so:

```
userProfile:FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

db.object('/users/'+auth.uid,{ preserveSnapshot: true })
    .subscribe(snapshot => {
       this.userProfile = snapshot;
});
```

In my HTML I can render out the object with the following:

```
{{ userService.userProfile | json  }}

OUTPUT rendered is:  { "email": "sdfsdf@fffdsfsdf22.com", "provider": "password" } // THIS is GREAT!!!! now I just need to extract the email... and will need more values later
```

Now I just need to render the email value... but nothing I do works, things I have tried that render no result

```
{{  userService.userProfile.email }} //nothing    
{{ userService.userProfile.email | json }} //nothing
{{ userService.userProfile.email | json | async }} //nothing
{{ userService.userProfile.email | async }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile.email ) | async }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile.email ) | json }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile?.email ) | json }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile?.email ) | async }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile)?.email  | async }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile)?.email  | json }} //nothing
{{ ( userService.userProfile)?.email }} //nothing
{{ ( userService)?.userProfile.email }} //nothing
{{ userService?.userProfile?.email }} //nothing
{{ userService?.userProfile?.email | async }} //nothing
{{ userService?.userProfile?.email | json }} //nothing
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out why it works at a high level, but not output a specific property.

Comment: what's the `userService`?

Comment: userService was the parent component it was injected from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few days ago. Please try:

```
snapshot.val()
```